# Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hook-form

I'm using firebase 9.1.0 version and with react-hook-form 7.17.0 version.

FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

this is error when i click submit button.

It's my register code

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./RegisterPage.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const RegisterPage = () => {
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm();
  const password = useRef();
  password.current = watch("password");

  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
   
    try {
      const auth = getAuth();
      let createdUser = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        data.email,
        data.password
      );
      createdUser();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="auth-wrapper">
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <h3>Register</h3>
      </div>
     
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>Email</label>
      
        <input
          name="email"
          type="email"
          {...register("email", { required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
        />
      
        {errors.email && <p>erros.email.This email field is required</p>}
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          name="name"
          tye="text"
          {...register("name", { required: true, maxLength: 10 })}
        />
      
        {errors.name && errors.name.type === "required" && (
          <p>erros.name.This name field is required</p>
        )}
        {errors.name && errors.name.type === "maxLength" && (
          <p>erros.name.Your input exceed maximum length</p>
        )}
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          {...register("password", { required: true, minLength: 6 })}
        />
        {errors.password && errors.password.type === "required" && (
          <p>errors.password.This password field is required</p>
        )}
        {errors.password && errors.password.minLength === "required" && (
          <p>errors.password.Password must have at least 6 characters</p>
        )}
        <label>Password Confirm</label>
        <input
          type="password_confirm"
          type="password"
          {...register("password_confirm", {
            required: true,
           
            validate: (value) => value === password.current,
          })}
        />
        {errors.password_confirm &&
          errors.password_confirm.type === "required" && (
            <p>errors.password_confirm.This Password confirm is required</p>
          )}
        {errors.password_confirm &&
          errors.password_confirm.type === "validate" && (
            <p>errors.password_confirm.The passwords do not match</p>
          )}
        <input type="submit" />
        <Link style={{ color: "gray", textDecoration: "none" }}>
        
        </Link>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegisterPage;
```

It's my firebase code

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/storage";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ,
  authDomain: ,
  projectId:,
  storageBucket: ,
  messagingSenderId: ,
  appId: ,
  measurementId: ,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default app;
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

please.. i want to resolve this problem

Comment: Where do you import that second file?

Comment: What is the second file??.. 미안 ..나 코린이라 ㅠㅠ

Comment: The file you posted with the title "It's my firebase code". Do you import it anywhere?

Comment: nope.. , you mean is import firebase in my register file ? like import firebase from "absolute path" ??

Comment: If you never import the file, then it will not run. If it does not run, then it does not call `initializeApp`. You need to import that file somewhere in your app.

Comment: I got it!!, thanks for explaining this to me. i love you